# For all $x \in \Bbb R$ there exists a $y \in (-\infty, 1)$ such that $3yx^2+y-x=0$

Tags: functions, logic, quantifiers

I have this question:

> Prove that for all real numbers $x$ there exist a number $y$ in the interval $(-\infty, 1)$ such that $$3x^2y+y-x=0$$

---

I proved that the range of the function
$$y = \frac{x}{3x^2 + 1}$$
is $(-1/2\sqrt{3},1/2\sqrt{3})$.
But the teacher said I should use another way.
I didn't find any.

Comment: Your header does not match the body of your post.  Do you mean $x^2y+y-x=0$ or $3x^2+y-x=0$?  And when you speak of the "range of the function", what function do you mean?

Comment: @haitham: What results/techniques do you have available?

Comment: I mean the function y = x/(3x^2+1)

Comment: Surely not $y=\frac x{3x^2+1}$....  That has range $\left( -\frac 13, \frac 13\right)$.

Comment: If 3x^2y+ y- x= 0 then 3yx^2- x+ y.  By the quadratic formula, x= (1+/- sqrt(1- 4y6

Comment: Sorry I meant 1/3

Comment: Well, to solve the problem all you need is to show that $y<1$ which is straight forward.

Comment: How can I prove that y<1?

Comment: Its range is $(-1/2\sqrt{3},1/2\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: @haitham: Do you know how to differentiate to find, maxima, minima?

Comment: Yes, the derivative should equal to 0? But again the culculas is not allowed just simple algebra.        What about my approach is it correct?

Comment: @haitham: Correct.

Comment: Well, I am going to use this approach thanks a lot.

Comment: @haitam: let's see: If you plug in 0, you get 0. You can tell that as x grows ( for x>0) , you see the expression approaches 1/3. If x grows and is negative. Can you see it?

Comment: Yes, but @lulu said I should prove that y <1, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The universe is the set of real numbers.

$\forall x\exists y<1:3x^2y+y-x=0$

$\iff\forall x\exists y<1:3x^2y+y=x$

$\iff\forall x\exists y<1:y(3x^2+1)=x$

$\iff\forall x\exists y<1:y=\frac{x}{3x^2+1}$, because we know that $3x^2+1\not=0$

$\iff\forall x\exists y(y<1\land y=\frac{x}{3x^2+1})$

$\iff\forall x\exists y(y=\frac{x}{3x^2+1}\land y<1)$

$\iff\forall x\exists y(y=\frac{x}{3x^2+1}\land \frac{x}{3x^2+1}<1)$

$\iff\forall x(\exists y(y=\frac{x}{3x^2+1})\land \frac{x}{3x^2+1}<1)$

$\iff\forall x\frac{x}{3x^2+1}<1$

$\iff\forall x:x<3x^2+1$, because we know that $3x^2+1>0$

$\iff\forall x:3x^2-x+1>0$

$\iff\forall x:x^2-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}>0$

$\iff\forall x:(x-\frac{1}{6})^2-(\frac{1}{6})^2+\frac{1}{3}>0$

$\iff\forall x:(x-\frac{1}{6})^2-\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{3}>0$

$\iff\forall x:(x-\frac{1}{6})^2>\frac{-11}{36}$, which is true, because the square of every real number is positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I am looking for .any other I ideas?

Comment: @haitham I'm glad I could help! What exactly are you refering to when you say "other ideas"? If you meant other ways of proving the statement, I'm afraid none come to mind.

Comment: yes, I mean some other ways. But no problem your answer and @lone student 's one were really helpful

Answer (score 2):

Observe that, the given polynomial is exactly quadratic with respect to the variable $x$. You have:

$$
\begin{align}
&3x^2y+y-x=0\\
\iff &3yx^2-x+y=0\\
&\Delta_x=1-12y^2\ge 0\\
\iff &-\frac {1}{2\sqrt 3}\leq y\leq \frac {1}{2\sqrt 3}
\end{align}
$$

This result tells us, $\forall x\in\mathbb R$ if $3x^2+y-x=0$, then $-\frac {1}{2\sqrt 3}\leq y\leq \frac {1}{2\sqrt 3}$ which is logically equivalent to the original statement.

Finally, we see that

$$
\begin{align}
-&\frac {1}{2\sqrt 3}\leq y\leq \frac {1}{2\sqrt 3}\\
\implies &y\in\left(-\infty, 1\right).
\end{align}
$$

This completes the proof.

You can also get a stronger result here:

> $\forall x \in \mathbb R$, there exists a $y \in \left[-\frac {1}{2\sqrt 3},\frac {1}{2\sqrt 3}\right]$, such that
> $$3yx^2+y-x=0$$ holds.

---

Remember that, you can also reach the result in a shorter way:

We observe that, if $x≤0$ the statement is obviously trivial. Therefore, we analyze the case $x>0$. Then applying the AM-GM inequality, you have:

$$
\begin{align}
y=\frac {x}{3x^2+1}&<\frac{x}{2\sqrt 3x}\\
&=\frac {1}{2\sqrt 3}\\
&<1.\end{align}
$$

This also proves the original statement.

Comment: Why $3yx^2+y-x=0$ is the same as $3x^2-x+y=0$.  I think you forgot the the variable $y$ in the leading term.

Comment: @haitham The answer is expanded also fixed.

Comment: Well, I got it, thanks a lot.